# I get System.InvalidOperationException when trying to run the web app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and EF, and I'm trying to run the following code:

```
if (!context.UserCourses.Any())
{
   if (!courseId1.Equals(int.MinValue))
     context.UserCourses.Add(new UserCourse { UserId = userId, CourseId = courseId1 });

   if (!courseId2.Equals(int.MinValue))
     context.UserCourses.Add(new UserCourse { UserId = userId, CourseId = courseId2 });

   if (!courseId3.Equals(int.MinValue))
     context.UserCourses.Add(new UserCourse { UserId = userId, CourseId = courseId3 });

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'UserCourse' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same
>   key value for {'UserId'} is already being tracked. When attaching
>   existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
>   key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.'

Let me know if you need more details or code.

Please help me on this as I can't continue with my web app.

**Later edit**: you may find below the entire method, located in **VOD.Database.Migrations.DbInitializer**:

```
public static void Initialize(VODContext context)
{
    var description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
    var email = "a@b.c";
    var adminRoleId = string.Empty;
    var userId = string.Empty;

    if (context.Users.Any(r => r.Email.Equals(email)))
        userId = context.Users.First(r => r.Email.Equals(email)).Id;

    if (!userId.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        if (!context.Instructors.Any())
        {
            var instructors = new List<Instructor>
            {
                new Instructor
                {
                    Name = "John Doe",
                    Description = description.Substring(20, 50),
                    Thumbnail = "/images/Ice-Age-Scrat-icon.png"
                },

                new Instructor
                {
                    Name = "Jane Doe",
                    Description = description.Substring(30, 40),
                    Thumbnail = "/images/Ice-Age-Scrat-icon.png"
                }
            };
            context.Instructors.AddRange(instructors);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.Courses.Any())
        {
            var instructorId1 = context.Instructors.First().Id;
            var instructorId2 = int.MinValue;
            var instructor = context.Instructors.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

            if (instructor != null) instructorId2 = instructor.Id;
            else instructorId2 = instructorId1;

            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
                new Course
                {
                    InstructorId = instructorId1,
                    Title = "Course 1",
                    Description = description,
                    ImageUrl = "/images/course1.jpg",
                    MarqueeImageUrl = "/images/laptop.jpg"
                },

                new Course
                {
                    InstructorId = instructorId2,
                    Title = "Course 2",
                    Description = description,
                    ImageUrl = "/images/course2.jpg",
                    MarqueeImageUrl = "/images/laptop.jpg"
                },

                new Course {
                    InstructorId = instructorId1,
                    Title = "Course 3",
                    Description = description,
                    ImageUrl = "/images/course3.jpg",
                    MarqueeImageUrl = "/images/laptop.jpg"
                }
            };
            context.Courses.AddRange(courses);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        var courseId1 = int.MinValue;
        var courseId2 = int.MinValue;
        var courseId3 = int.MinValue;

        if (context.Courses.Any())
        {
            courseId1 = context.Courses.First().Id;

            var course = context.Courses.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
            if (course != null) courseId2 = course.Id;

            course = context.Courses.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
            if (course != null) courseId3 = course.Id;
        }

        if (!context.UserCourses.Any())
        {
            if (!courseId1.Equals(int.MinValue))
                context.UserCourses.Add(new UserCourse { UserId = userId, CourseId = courseId1 });

            if (!courseId2.Equals(int.MinValue))
                context.UserCourses.Add(new UserCourse { UserId = userId, CourseId = courseId2 });

            if (!courseId3.Equals(int.MinValue))
                context.UserCourses.Add(new UserCourse { UserId = userId, CourseId = courseId3 });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.Modules.Any())
        {
            var modules = new List<Module>
            {
                new Module { Course = context.Find<Course>(courseId1), Title = "Modeule 1" },
                new Module { Course = context.Find<Course>(courseId1), Title = "Modeule 2" },
                new Module { Course = context.Find<Course>(courseId2), Title = "Modeule 3" }
            };
            context.Modules.AddRange(modules);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        var moduleId1 = int.MinValue;
        var moduleId2 = int.MinValue;
        var moduleId3 = int.MinValue;
        if (context.Modules.Any())
        {
            moduleId1 = context.Modules.First().Id;

            var module = context.Modules.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
            if (module != null) moduleId2 = module.Id;
            else moduleId2 = moduleId1;

            module = context.Modules.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
            if (module != null) moduleId3 = module.Id;
            else moduleId3 = moduleId1;
        }

        if (!context.Videos.Any())
        {
            var videos = new List<Video>
        {
            new Video { ModuleId = moduleId1, CourseId = courseId1,
            Title = "Video 1 Title",
            Description = description.Substring(1, 35),
            Duration = 50, Thumbnail = "/images/video1.jpg",
            Url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJFyzpBcaCY"
        },
            new Video { ModuleId = moduleId1, CourseId = courseId1,
            Title = "Video 2 Title",
            Description = description.Substring(5, 35),
            Duration = 45, Thumbnail = "/images/video2.jpg",
            Url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJFyzpBcaCY"
        },
            new Video { ModuleId = moduleId1, CourseId = courseId1,
            Title = "Video 3 Title",
            Description = description.Substring(10, 35),
            Duration = 41, Thumbnail = "/images/video3.jpg",
            Url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJFyzpBcaCY"
        },
            new Video { ModuleId = moduleId3, CourseId = courseId2,
            Title = "Video 4 Title",
            Description = description.Substring(15, 35),
            Duration = 41, Thumbnail = "/images/video4.jpg",
            Url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJFyzpBcaCY"
        },
            new Video { ModuleId = moduleId2, CourseId = courseId1,
            Title = "Video 5 Title",
            Description = description.Substring(20, 35),
            Duration = 42, Thumbnail = "/images/video5.jpg",
            Url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJFyzpBcaCY"
        }
        };
            context.Videos.AddRange(videos);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.Downloads.Any())
        {
            var downloads = new List<Download>
            {
                new Download{ModuleId = moduleId1, CourseId = courseId1,
                    Title = "ADO.NET 1 (PDF)", Url = "https://some-url" },

                new Download{ModuleId = moduleId1, CourseId = courseId1,
                    Title = "ADO.NET 2 (PDF)", Url = "https://some-url" },

                new Download{ModuleId = moduleId3, CourseId = courseId2,
                    Title = "ADO.NET 1 (PDF)", Url = "https://some-url" }
            };

            context.Downloads.AddRange(downloads);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

Code from **VOD.Database.Contexts.VODContext** can be found below:

```
public class VODContext : IdentityDbContext<VODUser>
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Download> Downloads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public VODContext(DbContextOptions<VODContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Composite key
        builder.Entity<UserCourse>().HasKey(uc => new { uc.UserId, uc.CourseId });

        // Restrict cascading deletes
        foreach (var relationship in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code from **VOD.Common.Entities.UserCourse**:

```
public class UserCourse
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public VODUser User { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that the app is working only if I have the table dbo.AspNetUsers empty or if the UserName from the mentioned table is not the "a@b.c" - which is declared in a var, in DbInitializer.cs.

Comment: It seems like `UserId` is defined as a `Key` for your entity. Entity Framework is telling you that you cannot insert two entities that share the same key. Most of the time, you would let Entity Framework handle the key generation and not set them yourself.

Comment: are there any other code in this method?

Comment: It's complaining that you are trying to add a new `UserCourse` with the same `UserId` key. Might be that your 3 if statements shown all evaluate to true. Please share your `UserCourse` model and additional code so we can further assist.

Comment: I have just included additional code in the Later edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you use the `[Key]` to set the primary key in the model, and then use Fluent API to set the composite key.

You should remove the `[Key]` Data Annotations in `UserCourse`

```
public class UserCourse
{
   //[Key]
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public VODUser User { get; set; }
   public int CourseId { get; set; }
   public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

You could refer to the documentation on [how to set the Key(primary) in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys).

Comment: I have tried to remove the `[Key]` from `UserCourse` but I get the following exception: _Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'. SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_UserCourses_UserId'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserCourses'. The duplicate key value is (203fb77f-3a90-46df-817e-bcfaa5dc0eda).
The statement has been terminated._ on the line `context.SaveChanges();` from the block `if (!context.UserCourses.Any())`.

Comment: @onetwo , Did you  re-migrate and update the database after  removing the `[Key] `from `UserCourse`?

Comment: Thank you, @Xueli Chen. It works now. Also, thank you germi, as this is the solution but I did not re-migrate and update the database.